Need a regular expression to process movie titles
I have thousands of movies and most of the titles are of the form:
This.Is.The.Movie.Title.yyyy.details.of.the.resolution.and.audio.format.mkv
I want to convert them to this:
This Is The Movie Title - yyyy.details.of.the.resolution.and.audio.format.mkv
I have managed to get a regular expression to match to the yyyy part and I'm using this with a macro in TextMate to then search and replace the periods in the text prior to the year, with spaces. But this is very clunky.
This is what I have so far:
(\.)(19[2-9]|20[0-2])\d\.
Could someone please suggest how to expand this to perform the whole match and replacement? It is beyond my current regexp skills.
My workaround is to use the macro, which works but is not an elegant solution

This will be difficult to achieve with a single regex.

Maybe you could just replace \.((?:19[2-9]|20[0-2])\d.*)? with " (?1- $1)" (without quotes, untested). Assuming it supports the boost replacement syntax mentioned in the manual and sounds like it uses the oniguruma regex library - confusing somehow.

@bobblebubble It does look simpler than mine, but it may not work if the movie title has a year in it that the third test case demonstrate the issue. Although OP didn't mention it.

For what I see, TextMate supports PCRE features like conditional replacement, which made a single substitution possible.

Regex:

\.(?=.*\.(?:19[2-9]|20[0-2])\d\.)|\.(.*)$


Substitution

 (?1:- $1)

↑ There's a leading whitespace which is necessary
See the live demo (the conditional substitution syntax is slightly different, but it works the same)

How it works
There are two conditions:
\.(?=.*\.(?:19[2-9]|20[0-2])\d\.)    # match a dot, but after the dot, it must has a year somewhere in the title. Meaning match all dots before the produce year
|                                    # OR
\.(.*)$                              # match a dot, as well as everything after it, and put it in group 1

 (?1:- $1)     # replace the dot with a whitespace, then if the group 1 has captured something, adding `- ` with the group content, which is everything after the produce year.

Proof that it works in TextMate 2.0:


Very nice the animated GIF showcase ️

This is brilliant and exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

One can match the following regular expression.
rgx = /\.(?=(.*)\b(?:19[2-9]|20[0-2])\d\b)/

As seen here the correct periods are matched.
Note that while TextMate uses the Oniguruma regular expression library and I have selected the PCRE engine at the link, in this case the two engines produce the same result.
When there is a match capture group 1 will hold a string comprised of the characters between the matched period and the first digit of the following year on the same line. This can be seen in the right panel at the link. If this captured string is empty the matched period should be replaced with ' - '; else it should be replaced with ' '.
Note that Ruby also uses the Oniguruma regex engine. If Ruby rather than Textmate were being used and the variable text held the string one could implement the needed logic with the following expression.
text.gsub(rgx) { $1.empty? ? ' - ' : ' ' }

Ruby demo
This expression causes every match of rgx to be replaced with ' - ' if capture group holds an empty string and to be replaced with ' ' otherwise.
Though I am not familiar with Textmate scripts I would expect it should not be difficult to create one that implements this Ruby expression.

This will be difficult to achieve via a single regex replacement.  But, we can easily do it via 2 regex replacements:
-- replacement 1
Find:    \.(?=[A-Z][a-z]*\.)
Replace: (a single space)

-- replacement 2
Find:    \.(?=\d{4}\.)
Replace:  -   (hyphen with one space on each side)


if you using javascript:
this is the regex that can find the . before year, and the 4 digits year: (see the group 1 and group 2).
.*(.)(\d{4})\..*

this is the screenshot taken from https://regex101.com/

this is the code generated by the site:
 const regex = /.*(.)(\d{4})\..*/gm;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('.*(.)(\\d{4})\\..*', 'gm')

const str = `This.Is.The.Movie.Title.2014.details.of.the.resolution.and.audio.format.mkv`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}


if you using javascript ... the OP has tagged its question with Textmate, which is an iOS text editor, not JavaScript.  Also, your intended regex covers only one part of the desired replacement.
